# SQL - Duplicate rows with left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am trying to pull through the number of days taken sick leave and employee info.

I have two tables

One is a table where sick leave is recorded (LVE) and the other is a employee table which is a view containing staff data (Staff) eg the employment status column(pos_statusa)

With my query below, I am getting duplicate results - The same employeenumber, leave type, leave start, leave end, and position status.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT RTRIM(DET_NUMBER) AS DET_NUMBERA,
    RTRIM(LVE_TYPE_CD) AS LVE_TYPE_CD,
    l.LVE_START,
    l.LVE_END, 
    l.LVE_HOUR_TKN,
    l.LVE_DAY_TAKE, 
    e.pos_statusa
FROM            dbo.LVE as l
LEFT JOIN Staff as e
ON l.DET_NUMBER = e.DET_NUMBERA COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
WHERE (LVE_START > = '2017-02-01'   
AND LVE_END < '2018-02-01')
AND LVE_TYPE_CD IN ('SIC','USIC')
```

Cheers

Comment: You need to edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: It sounds like "group by" should be used at some point.

Comment: With SQL questions please post sample data and example results. It's hard to answer questions like this otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding 'Distinct' after SELECT?

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the records having data in LVE table and staff table both, after fulfilling your conditions then use JOIN instead of left JOIN.

```
SELECT RTRIM(DET_NUMBER) AS DET_NUMBERA,
    RTRIM(LVE_TYPE_CD) AS LVE_TYPE_CD,
    l.LVE_START,
    l.LVE_END, 
    l.LVE_HOUR_TKN,
    l.LVE_DAY_TAKE, 
    e.pos_statusa
FROM            dbo.LVE as l
JOIN Staff as e
ON l.DET_NUMBER = e.DET_NUMBERA COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
WHERE (LVE_START > = '2017-02-01'   
AND LVE_END < '2018-02-01')
AND LVE_TYPE_CD IN ('SIC','USIC')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help.

It looks like a simple 'DISTINCT' has done the trick!

Comment: This seems to be just a repeat of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48757087).